# Can every SU(4) matrix be written as a product of of these 4 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Consider a general $SU(4)$ matrix
$$U=e^{i a^j T^j},$$
where the generators $T^i$ are chosen in the basis
$$\{T\} = 1_2 \times \sigma^i, \quad \sigma^i \times 1_2, \quad \sigma^i \times \sigma^j, $$
for $i,j = 1,2,3$. How would I go about proving or disproving that every $U$ can be written as the following product.
$$U = e^{i(1_2 \times \sigma^j)b^j } \; e^{i(\sigma^k \times 1_2)c^k }\; e^{i((\sigma^l \times \sigma^1)d^{l} + (\sigma^m \times \sigma^2)e^{m} )}\;e^{i(\sigma^n \times \sigma^3)f^n },$$
for some $b,c,d,e,f$.

Edit: I am aware of the general Lie theory property (see for example page 3 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0202002.pdf) paper) that if one can divide the generators $\{T\}$ into two subsets $L(K)=\{k^m\}$ and $L(P)=\{ p^n \}$ with the following commutation relations:
$$[k^{m_1},k^{m_2}]\in L(K), \quad [k^m,p^n]\in L(P), \quad [p^{n_1},p^{n_2}]\in L(K),$$
then one can decompose any $U$ as
$$ U = e^{i \alpha^m k^m} e^{i \beta^n p^n} .$$
This allows me to pull out the the first two exponentials in my desired decomposition above, by setting
$$L(K) = \{1_2 \times \sigma^i, \quad \sigma^i \times 1_2\}, \quad L(P) = \{ \sigma^i \times \sigma^j\}.$$
However, the same `trick' does not allow me to decompose any further. I don't know if this means it cannot be done at all though...

Answer (score 1):

The generators of *su(4)* in the fundamental are 4×4 traceless hermitian matrices, so 15 independent ones.

The matrices in your basis *{T}* are manifestly traceless and hermitian! Convince yourself of the obviousness of the fact. They are 3+3+9=15 in number, and, again, their independence should be obvious.

They are then a good basis of *su(4)*, so the generic group element of *SU(4)* may be written as the exponential whose phase is their generic linear combination.

So you must convince yourself that your quadruple exponential product does not represent a mere subgroup. The exponents of the first two exponentials commute, so you may combine them into one, by the trivial limit of the CBH identity. I'm not sure how much rigor you require, but, to lower nontrivial orders of CBH-combining the 3 remaining exponentials you have a full span.

*NB.* Near the identity,  to linear order of your 15 ("angle") parameters, you completely cover all 15 directions of your manifold and tangent space.  Your original question asked whether higher orders could conspire to leave  "uncovered  regions" of that manifold. Presentation theory addresses these issues.

Comment: I agree that at the low order of CBH it seems like it should work, but I don't think it's enough. I have edited my question to include a known property of Lie group/algebra theory that says I can definitely `pull out' the first two exponentials (which, as you say, commute with each other), but I'm not sure my full desired decomposition makes sense. I suspect there are only certain decompositions that are allowed. Otherwise, if we just looked at low order CBH terms we could imagine writing $U$ as a product of 15 different exponentials, each corresponding to one of the 15 generators...

Comment: Ach, no, you've basically reedited you  original question  into a much broader question, however that one is close to some original subquestion you had... Not nice. In your shoes, I'd break up the questions, and write you second one, close to this now, more consistently. The first two groupings are commuting *su(2)* subalgebras,  but you are trying to evoke a Gell-Mann V/A chiral algebra structure which is not there.  Organizing group element sets is closer to presentation theory than to Lie Algebras....

Comment: My question has always been if every $SU(4)$ Lie group matrix can be written as the product of the above 4 exponentials. I knew the basis of generators $\{T\}$ I wrote spans the Lie algebra $mathfrak{su}(4)$ but I had no idea if I can split into 4 exponentials. The edit was just presenting the only relevant theorem I found that could give me an indication, as well showing the level of rigour I am looking for.

Comment: As you say in your answer, I think I am interested in knowing whether there are uncovered regions of the manifold in this parametrisation. You say presentation theory addresses this. Could you please point me towards a useful theorem or book? thank you :)

Comment: I completely misread your question, then..  I read it as a question on bases... nothing involving exponentialscares about bases, only subalgebras, ideals, etc!  Vile kin has written *the* books on Lie manifolds... but I ve lost track...

Comment: Baum Y Vilenkin, some with Klimyk.